# How Do I Adjust The Star Wars: Saga Edition Challenge Level Formula for More Players?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

The guidelines for building encounters in Saga Edition use an average of the total CLs of the enemies and hazards and divides it by 3. A result that is within three levels of the average level of a party of four player-characters is more or less a fitting encounter. I've read this both in the books and in the Encounter Design 101 web supplement. The trouble is, my game has five player-characters. How would I adjust the formula to work with this additional player?

Comment: Welp, my rule of thumb as a DM is round down.

Comment: No, I mean, I have five players, while the Encounter Level formula is designed for four players. I'm asking what I would change in the formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 247 of the SW Saga Edition Revised Core Rulebook has this at the end of the paragraph on Combining Different CLs:

> Note that these calculations are based on the assumption that there are four heroes at the party. For each additional hero, subtract 1 from the result. For each missing hero, add 1 to the result. [Result here refers to SUM(CLs)/3]

Answer (score 2):

5 players is 25% more than 4 players, so multiply the total CL value by 1.25, and this way it should roughly balance the numbers ratio. Or just adding an extra unit for each 4 units should also work? Balance as needed as the game progresses.